# How to convert this simple Entity Framework query into a standard SQL query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have no experience with the .NET **Entity Framework** and I have some doubts about what exactly do this query:

```
using (MyCorpo.EarlyWarnings.Model.EarlyWarningsEntities context = new Model.EarlyWarningsEntities()) 
{
    DBContext.SetTimeout(context);    

    model.VulnerabilitySeverityAverage = (from x in context.VulnerabilityAlertDocuments select x.Severity).Average();
}
```

(Where the type of the model.VulnerabilitySeverityAverage is simply a string)

So I think that **VulnerabilityAlertDocuments** map the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument database table** because into the **EarlyWarningsEntities** I have something this line:

```
public DbSet<VulnerabilityAlertDocument> VulnerabilityAlertDocuments { get; set; }
```

So I am executing a query on the **VulnerabilityAlertDocuments** DbSet object that represent a query on my **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** table on my database. Is it correct?

So what exatly do the previous query?

I think that it select the **Severity** field value of all records in the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** table and calculate the avarage value from all these value.

Is it my reasoning correct?

How can I convert this entity query in a classic SQL query? Someone can help me?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I convert this entity query in a classic SQL query?

To see actual SQL you can just call `.ToString()` method on your query;

```
var sql = (from x in context.VulnerabilityAlertDocuments select x.Severity).Average().ToString();
```

> So I am executing a query on the VulnerabilityAlertDocuments DbSet
>   object that represent a query on my VulnerabilityAlertDocument table
>   on my database. Is it correct?

Yes

```
So what exatly do the previous query?
```

Your query will average value in Severity column of ValnerabilityAlertDocuments table.
your translated query would've looked simular to this:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    AVG([Extent1].[Severity]) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[ValnerabilityAlertDocuments] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Also you could try to use such tool as [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

UPDATE:
Just adding [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to list of tools (thanks to Dismissile)

Comment: LINQPad is also a great tool for seeing what SQL your EF queries produce.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Average(x.Severity)
From VulnerabilityAlertDocuments x
```

Thats assuming your table is called "VulnerabilityAlertDocuments"

try again

Comment: mmm for what DBMS is your query? on Microsoft SQL Server go into error

Comment: It's because there is no 'x' variable